# Kernel density estimation bandwidth

Tags: kernel-smoothing

I'm trying to reimplement ScipPy's `gaussian_kde` to understand how exactly the estimation works so that I can reimplement it in C++ later. I'm following [this article](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/AV0405/MISHRA/kde.html) and I assumed that I just need to sum a number of gaussians and that's my result.

My code:

```
points = np.array([3.0, 4.0, 6.0], dtype=float)

def gaussian_kernel(u):
    return np.exp(-0.5 * u**2) / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)

bw = 0.6

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.zeros_like(x)
for i in points:
    g = gaussian_kernel((x - i) / bw) / len(points)
    plt.plot(x, g, alpha=0.1)
    y += g
plt.plot(x, y)

kde = gaussian_kde(points, bw_method=bw)
plt.plot(x, kde(x))
```

However, I realized that the bandwith factor in `gaussian_kde` doesn't do what I expected it to do and I'm getting results like this:

[image]

Scaling of the gaussians in my code is clearly wrong, but also the width of the gaussians in `gaussian_kde` depends on the number of points in the data set. I have tried reading the code, but the math is a bit above my head (I'm not very familiar with statistics).

Can someone explain what exactly does the `bw_factor` parameter mean and how does it affect the individual gaussians?

Comment: Could you explain what your graphic is showing and why it does not seem reasonable?

Comment: My goal is that the lines are the same, i.e. my `y` is exactly the same as `kde(x)`, but in the picture you can see that SciPy's KDE (purple) is more smooth than mine (cyan) and also it's higher. I guess I'm missing some scaling somewhere, but I don't see where.

Comment: It's clear you are using a narrower bandwidth than employed for the purple line and that your scaling is incorrect.  The scaling is incorrect because you are not incorporating the effect of the changeable bandwidth in the definition of the kernel. Nothing can be said concerning the choice of bandwidth, because you haven't explained where it came from or how it compares to that of the purple KDE.